# Spark keeps submitting tasks to dead executor

Tags: java, apache-spark

i am working on apache spark and i am facing a very weird issue. One of the executors fail because of OOM and its shut down hooks clear all the storage (memory and disk) but apparently driver keeps submitting the failed tasks on the same executor due to PROCESS_LOCAL tasks.

Now that the storage on that machine is cleared, all the retried tasks also fail causing the whole stage to fail (after 4 retries)

What i don't understand is, how couldn't driver know that the executor is in shut down and will not be able to execute any tasks.

Configuration:

- heartbeat interval: 60s
- Network timeout: 600s

Logs to confirm that executor is accepting tasks post shutdown

```java
20/09/29 20:26:32 ERROR [Executor task launch worker for task 138513] Executor: Exception in task 6391.0 in stage 17.0 (TID 138513)
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
20/09/29 20:26:32 ERROR [Executor task launch worker for task 138513] SparkUncaughtExceptionHandler: Uncaught exception in thread Thread[Executor task launch worker for task 138513,5,main]
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
20/09/29 20:26:32 INFO [pool-8-thread-1] DiskBlockManager: Shutdown hook called
20/09/29 20:26:35 ERROR [Executor task launch worker for task 138295] Executor: Exception in task 6239.0 in stage 17.0 (TID 138295)
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/1/spark/spark-ba168da6-dc11-4e15-bd95-1e58198c81e7/executor-8dea198c-741a-4733-8fbb-df57241acdd5/blockmgr-1fc6b30a-c24e-4bb2-a133-5e411cef810f/35/temp_shuffle_b5df90ac-78de-48e3-9c2d-891f8b2ce1fa (No such file or directory)
20/09/29 20:26:36 ERROR [Executor task launch worker for task 139484] Executor: Exception in task 6587.0 in stage 17.0 (TID 139484)
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Block rdd_3861_6587 was not found even though it's read-locked
20/09/29 20:26:42 WARN [Thread-2] ShutdownHookManager: ShutdownHook '$anon$2' timeout, java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: null
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:205) ~[?:1.8.0_172]
20/09/29 20:26:44 ERROR [Executor task launch worker for task 140256] Executor: Exception in task 6576.3 in stage 17.0 (TID 140256)
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/1/spark/spark-ba168da6-dc11-4e15-bd95-1e58198c81e7/executor-8dea198c-741a-4733-8fbb-df57241acdd5/blockmgr-1fc6b30a-c24e-4bb2-a133-5e411cef810f/30/rdd_3861_6576 (No such file or directory)
20/09/29 20:26:44 INFO [dispatcher-event-loop-0] Executor: Executor is trying to kill task 6866.1 in stage 17.0 (TID 140329), reason: stage cancelled
20/09/29 20:26:47 INFO [pool-8-thread-1] ShutdownHookManager: Shutdown hook called
20/09/29 20:26:47 DEBUG [pool-8-thread-1] Client: stopping client from cache: org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client@3117bde5
20/09/29 20:26:47 DEBUG [pool-8-thread-1] Client: stopping client from cache: org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client@3117bde5
20/09/29 20:26:47 DEBUG [pool-8-thread-1] Client: removing client from cache: org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client@3117bde5
20/09/29 20:26:47 DEBUG [pool-8-thread-1] Client: stopping actual client because no more references remain: org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client@3117bde5
20/09/29 20:26:47 DEBUG [pool-8-thread-1] Client: Stopping client
20/09/29 20:26:47 DEBUG [Thread-2] ShutdownHookManager: ShutdownHookManger complete shutdown
20/09/29 20:26:55 INFO [dispatcher-event-loop-14] CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend: Got assigned task 141510
20/09/29 20:26:55 INFO [Executor task launch worker for task 141510] Executor: Running task 545.1 in stage 26.0 (TID 141510)
```

(I have trimmed down the stack traces as those are just spark RDD shuffle read methods)

If we check the timestamps, then shutdown started at `20/09/29 20:26:32` and ended at `20/09/29 20:26:47`, in between this duration, driver sent all the retried tasks to the same executor and they all failed causing stage cancellation.

can someone help me understand this behavior ? Also let me know if anything else is required

Answer (score 0):

there is a configuration in spark, spark.task.maxFailures default is 4. so spark retry the task when it's failed.  and the Taskrunner will update the task status to driver. and driver will forward this status to taskschedulerimpl. in your case, only executor OOM and DiskBlockManager shutdown, but the driver is alive. i think the executor is alive as well. and will retry the task with same taskSetManager. the failed times of this task arrive 4 times, this stage will be cancelled, and executor will be killed.